# Changing default home page in Apache2

Tags: php, apache2, configure

My Directory structure is

`app
- index.php
home
- index.php
index.php`

I want users to view home/index.php every time they visit http://example.com but I want users to access http://example.com also if they navigate using the navigation also.

My question is, can I configure apache to make website default homepage other than the root directory. I don't mind if users get redirected to home/index.php first time.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. Just setup a vhost to have a DocumentRoot statement pointing to whatever you want your root directory to be. 
For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/my_site/home"
</VirtualHost>
```

But note that after this, whatever will be updir from the DocumentRoot path, will be outside the reach of Apache. You can however include files updir using require/include functions from PHP.

You may also want to have a Directory statement for specifying access rights to that dir. An example of that can be:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/my_site/home"

  <Directory "/var/www/my_site/home">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Also don't forget to restart Apache after any change made in the vhost config file.